# php artisan serve not working (laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have some problem when I tried to serve the application on my localhost.

When I run

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\BePunct>php artisan serve --host=admin.bepunct.test
```

I received this error

> Laravel development server started: http://admin.bepunct.test:8000
>   [Mon Mar 11 09:37:03 2019] PHP Warning:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in Unknown on line 0
>      [Mon Mar 11 09:37:03 2019] Failed to listen on admin.bepunct.test:8000 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. )

This is the my `env` setting: [.env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLMbf.png)

I have set on `/drivers/etc/hosts` to redirect the url to the localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error simply saying that the requested host is not found.
Please make sure your given host is referring to localhost domain.

```
127.0.0.1  admin.bepunct.test
```

Comment: @khairunnaim Glad to know that. If it works plz upvote and approve this answer.